# Headings should only be defined once

Tags: css, csslint

Just ran a decent amount of css through csslint, mainly to check for errors. 80% of the warnings I get are from defining the same header element more than once. So I was wondering what the best way to clean up these kind of styles would be...

```
h4 {
    color: red;
}

.archive h4 {
    color: green;
}
```

Keeping in mind I'm already using h1 - h6 styles elsewhere in the design.

Would it be better to use classes for this and then inherit the styles with mix-ins (i'm using stylus)?

```
h4 {
    color: red;
}

.archive-header {
    color: green;
}
```

While i'm at it, why does csslint warn against this? Are there performance hits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To get around it, sure... you're solution should work just fine.
2. CSS Lint warns against it because you shouldn't style the same headers differently. Here's a little excerpt from an [article talking more about the subject](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2011/09/06/style-headings-using-html5-sections/):

> When styling headings (or really anything) we want three big goals to be met:
>
> 1. **DRY** – Do not repeat yourself. We want to set headings once and never (ok, rarely!) repeat those font styles or selectors. This will make our site easier to maintain.
> 2. **Predictable** – The heading should look the same no matter where on the page it is placed. This will make creating new pages and content easier.
> 3. **Keep specificity low and selectors as simple as possible**. This will help with performance and keep the site from growing more and more tangled over time.
>
> No performance hits. If anything, it might even be [better](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/) to use a class name instead of a tag. The solution you proposed is almost a textbook recommendation of [how to make your website faster by Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#UseEfficientCSSSelectors).

Comment: Honestly, this warning can be ignored in some cases. `h1,h2,h3{margin:8px 0;letter-spacing:-1px;font-weight:900}` sets THREE defaults; then a further `h1{font-size:40px;border-bottom: 1px solid #eee}` is ONLY for `h1`. To conform to this rule, I would have to duplicate CSS styles to `h2,h3{}` and `h1{}` separately. Always question your linter.